# Detecting what jQuery UI's draggable function is hovering over

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm attempting to have the dragged element detect where it's hovering over on the `stop` event for the jQuery's UI draggable function. Here is my attempt, however to no avail:

```
$(".artwork").draggable({
    stop: function(e, ui){
        ui.mouseover(function(f){
            if(f.target.id == "wall")
            {
                alert("yes!");
            }
        });
    }
 });
```

I'm not too sure I fully understand how I'd be able to detect what element I'm hovering over on the drag's `stop` event.

Thanks!

Comment: did you console.log(ui) to see what you get?

Comment: `ui.helper.context` is what gives you currently dragged element and i don think you need to register a mouseover even inside that.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you using [droppable](http://jqueryui.com/droppable/) plugin too?

Comment: I'm not using the droppable plugin, just using draggable. And ill take a look at the `ui.helper.context`.

Comment: The `ui.helper.context` code returns the dragged element's name. I want what that element is hovered over on the `stop` event.

Comment: I think you may have to use droppable and the [over event](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-over)

Comment: Can you make an answer out of it? I'd like to see what you have in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might want to check `droppable`'s **over** event.

```
$(".droppable").droppable({
    over: function (event, ui) { 
       var yourCurrentlyHoveredElement = $(this); //the 'this' under over event
     } 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [docs](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-hoverClass), I believe the better way of doing this is

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({ hoverClass: "drop-hover" });
```