# How to get the position value of the element as it's being dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get the position of the element called "draggable" while it's being dragged so I can use the value for an if statement (for example, if "draggable" is placed on an image, display the number assigned to "draggable"). The console log shows each element's position, but I don't know how to make the values change according to where it's being dragged on the page. How do I go about this?

Using jquery-1.7.2.min.js

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('.draggable').draggable({
        cursor:'move',
        opacity: 0.7,
    var element = $('.draggable');
    var position = element.position();
    console.log("left:" + position.left + "top:" + position.top);
    });
$('.draggable').each(function(){
    var element = $(this);
    var offset1 = element.offset();
    console.log("left:" + offset1.left + "top:" + offset1.top);
  });
});
```

Comment: Something looks very wrong about the way you're initializing `draggable`. You shouldn't be declaring `var`s in there, as arguments to the initialize method.

Comment: @AndyHoffman I tried `$('.draggable').each(function(){});` and placed the `var`s in there. The console log now shows each element's position, but I don't know how to make the position values change according to where they're being dragged.

Comment: `var element = $('.draggable');`` selects all elements of that class, not the element being dragged.  In your second with `.each(` that just runs that function for each element with that class once...you need to hook into the event handler for the draggable. This is the documentation for that event handler. http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#event-drag

Comment: NOTE: "drag" will fire often, perhaps you want to use the "dragstop" event as a suggestion.

Comment: NOTE: Consider the droppable as described in this questions answers: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17139818/125981

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created a codepen for this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XGZLLW?editors=1111

```
<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me around</p>
</div>

$( function(){
  $('#draggable').draggable({
    cursor:'move',
    opacity: 0.7,
    drag: function(){
      var element = $('#draggable');
      var position = $(this).position();
      console.log(position.left + ", " position.top);    
    }
  });
});
```

You can hook into the drag event to do this.  I also highly recommend using a unique ID instead of class for this.

There is also good info in the docs for this: https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

UPDATE: To get this to work for multiple with the same class, you can take advantage of $(this) to grab the active element within the drag, like this:

```
$( function(){
  $('.draggable').draggable({
    cursor:'move',
    opacity: 0.7,
    drag: function(){
      var position = $(this).position();
      $(this).find(".xpos").html(position.left);
      $(this).find(".ypos").html(position.top);      
    }
  });
});
```

Also updated this on the pen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XGZLLW

Comment: Thanks so much, but it only works on one element (I have four different elements to move) and the position value keeps creating a new console line of the position every time I move it. How do I make this work on multiple elements not one, and is there a way to make the changing values display without creating new console lines?

Comment: I do not see the point of `var element = $('#draggable');` in the function at all in this answer